# MVC3 System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting Font does not render but Style does

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, charts

I am battling with the .net 4.0 Chart Controls and am currently stuck on why the font simply refuses to render. It shows as near unreadable overlapping characters. I'm sure the font is installed in my system.

Oddly the font stlye changes in accordance with the setting.![screen shot][1]

I also had a hard time discovering the Interval property where it was removing labels above the count of 9 until Interval was set to 1.  The interval property also behaved differently than the System.Web.Helpers.Chart() control which seems to ignore the setting. Lame!

Thanks for any help.

Razor Code..

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ChartSample")" alt="image" />//In Razer
```

Controller Code...

```
 public ActionResult ChartSample()
    {
        var chart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
        chart.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        chart.Width = Unit.Pixel(250);
        chart.Height = Unit.Pixel(2500);

        var series = new Series();
        series.ChartArea = "ca1";

        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
        //series.Font = new Font("Verdana", 8.25f, FontStyle.Regular);

        var myRandom = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var dp = new DataPoint();
            dp.AxisLabel = String.Format("{0}-{1}", i, Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4));
            dp.YValues = new double[] { myRandom.Next(5, 100) };
            series.Points.Add(dp);
        }


        chart.Series.Add(series);

        var area = new ChartArea("ca1");
        area.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = false;
        area.AxisX.Interval = 1;
        //area.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        //var labelStyle = new LabelStyle();
        //labelStyle.Enabled = true;
        //labelStyle.Font = new Font("Arial", 3f);
        area.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Verdana", 8.25f, FontStyle.Underline);//Why does it recognize the style but not the font!!!???

        chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png", "mychart.png");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm also considering low resolution as a possible culprit as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just give your chart a back color as follows:

```
 chart.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
```